# In JavaFX and scenebuilder project, how to use the setOnAction() method in Controller class

Tags: javafx

I am new to JavaFX and SceneBuilder.
I created an app using the SceneBuilder in Eclipse. (Right click FXML file > open with SceneBuilder)
Inside initialize method, I can not see the setOnAction method.

[image]

```
package application.controller;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class controller {

    

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField loginID;

    @FXML
    private JFXPasswordField passwordID;

    @FXML
    private ImageView loginButton;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        loginButton.setona
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: If you are new to JavaFX, I recommend sticking with the standard controls rather than using a third party library such as jfoenix.  Do that until you get the hang of everything, then go ahead and use other libraries or develop your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `loginButton` as an `ImageView`. `ImageView` does not have `setOnAction` method. use `setOnMouseClicked` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I just changed from ImageView to Button. Now I am able to use the setOnAction method.

Comment: Changing to button is the better option, nice choice.

Answer (score 0):

The onAction method is for generic actions and not every components have that method. if you want to fire an event when the user click the button you can use

```
 loginButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("click"));
```

now if you want to try to add the onAction handler you can simply add it adding it has event filter, but i am not sure it will work with imageview

```
  loginButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ANY, event -> ...)
```

Comment: If something is named loginButton, then it should be a Button, in which case it will respond to onAction, no need to also add a click handler and an event filter.  The actual problem as the asker noted in comments is that loginButton was assigned the wrong type, it was set to ImageView.  If needed, a button with an image can be created by setting a graphic on the button, but the button will still keep its functionality to respond to an action.

Comment: An event filter is not the same as an event handler (see the Oracle tutorial on JavaFX event bubbling).